# Depth Image background changes

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, kinect

I am using Kinect v2 to record the sequence of depth images.
when i plot the images in MATLAB, then images color is changing a lot. like this images
[image: Image1]
[image: Imag2]

In matlab the variable uint16 type.

My question is why it is changing? and how can i fix it?
Here is the code for plotting the images

```
for i=1:52
    imagesc(Depth(:,:,i));colormap gray; 
    pause(0.1);
end
```

Comment: duplicate post from same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908572/histogram-noramalization-for-normalizing-background-changes

Comment: @killogre in both the post image is same but the question is different..

Answer (score 0):

You should not scale the depth images independently of each other, if you want to visualize in a sequence that's visually consistent. All the more so considering that colormap(gray) gives you only 20 different levels.

Try something like:

```
m = min(Depth(:));
M = max(Depth(:));
scale = 1.0 / (M - m);
colormap(gray(256))
for i=1:52
  d = scale .* (Depth(:,:,i) - m);
  imagesc(d);
  pause(0.1);
end
```

Comment: I tried using the code you suggested. But the output is like that, [result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzf3ahwpvl8lerd/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: You probably have some frame(s) with a very low min or a very high max. Suggest you see if this is the case by histogramming the content of Depth, then you could perhaps center the range about the median depth.

Comment: All the frames have minimum value 0, but the maximum value is changes as it can be seen in above images. 
can you please tell me how can I normalise by histogramming the contents of depth?

Comment: There is no magic. Look at histograms of individual frames and at the cumulative one, that should tell you if there is a range of common levels that could be kept fixed throughout the sequence for visualization. Then threshold all frames within this range and display stretching the contrast. I recommend doing the analysis in Gimp or Photoshop.

Comment: I have no expertise in Gimp or Photoshop