# Histogram normalization for normalizing background changes

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram

I recorded a sequence of depth images using Kinect v2. But the background brightness is not constant. But It keeps changing from dark to light and light to dark (i.e) [image].
So I was thinking to use Histogram normalization of each image in a sequence to normalise the background to the same level. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: depth values are not supposed to change this drastically (unless the camera is moving). are you sure you are reading the stream into matlab correctly?

Comment: @killogre I am reading the stream into Matlab directly. I used C# program to capture the sequence of images, then i used MATLAB to visualize the images

Comment: @Andrey This question is related to the image processing and computer vision. so i asked here..

Comment: @Addee, I think that `dsp.stackexchange.com` will be more helpful to you, since there are more experts in image processing and computer vision there.

Comment: OK i posted my question there

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has a function for [histogram matching](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhistmatch.html?refresh=true) and their site has some great examples too

Just use any frame as the reference (I suggest using the first one, but there is no *real* reason to do so), and keep it for all the remaining frames. If you want to decrease processing time you can also try lowering the number of bins. For a `uint8` image there are usually 256 bins, but as you'll see in the link reducing it still produces favorable results

I don't know if kinect images are rgb or grayscale, for this example Im assuming they are grayscale

```erlang
kinect_images = Depth;
num_frames = size(kinect_images,3); %maybe 4, I don't know if kinect images
                                    %are grayscale(3) or RGB(4)

num_of_bins = 32;

%imhistmatch is a recent addition to matlab, use this variable to 
%indicate whether or not you have it
I_have_imhistmatch = true;

%output variable
equalized_images = cast(zeros(size(kinect_images)),class(kinect_images));

%stores first frame as reference
ref_image = kinect_images(:,:,1);   %if rgb you may need (:,:,:,1)
ref_hist = imhist(ref_image);

%goes through every frame and matches the histof
for ii=1:1:num_frames
    if (I_have_imhistmatch)
        %use this with newer versions of matlab
        equalized_images(:,:,ii) = imhistmatch(kinect_images(:,:,ii), ref_image, num_of_bins);
    else
        %use this line with older versions that dont have imhistmatch
        equalized_images(:,:,ii) = histeq(kinect_images(:,:,ii), ref_hist);
    end
end

implay(equalized_images)
```

Comment: thanks for the code. It is not matching the histogram of ref image to all images correctly. here is my [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mboh3flc82n31a4/Depth.mat?dl=0). Can you please check it

Comment: Histogram matches will almost never be 100% identical. The algorithm just does the best it can to match the CDFs of the two functions to one another. Think of it this way. You have a nice color image as reference and then you want to make an image match it that only has 2 colors on it. The two histograms won't even look close to one another.  I was going to try the code with your data then I noticed I don't even have `imhistmatch` so I just used `histeq` instead. I can see it doesn't match exactly, but as I mentioned earlier, thats to be expected